# Adding custom index in Drupal SOLR Search API

Tags: drupal, solr

Hi I have a requirement as below

I have a field collection which stores skill and years of experience. For example

Java 5 years
Spring 1 years

I have added the custom module to extract the skills to index , Ex : Java, Spring using
hook_entity_property_info_alter.

I also want to index the number of years for each skill, i.e., java_year_of_experience = 5 years, spring_years_of_experience = 1 years, etc...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Solr dynamic fields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Dynamic_fields).

Dynamic fields would allow to pass fields name that match certain patterns and are defined as below

e.g. `<dynamicField name="*__year_of_experience"  type="integer"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>`

- By this you can handle any number of *_year_of_experience fields.
- The fields will be created dynamically and need not be defined.

Comment: thanks for the reply Jayendra, I need to know how to handle this in Search API in Drupal,